# "No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting the below message while I am doing build in my Azure DevOps pipeline.  Here I am using Azure DevOps pipelines, VS2017 and Windows 2016.

> "No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:
>
> msbuild
>
> visualstudio
>
> vstest
>
> Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.161.0 "

This is failing when I'm using three agent jobs in single pipeline. If I run the same tasks in new pipeline it works fine. Could you please suggest the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by "Download Pipeline Artifacts@2" task.

It has been reported to the product group not long ago, and our engineers have released fixes that resolve compatibility issues. This issue has now been fixed. I apologize for the inconvenience here.

For details,please refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/859606/build-pipeline-failing-no-agent-found-in-pool-azur.html) on our Developer Community forum.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have removed the "Download Pipeline Artifacts@2" and added the "download build artifacts" and made some changes to match our requirements. We are able to build fine now.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, we were getting the error and this is what solved it:

I logged on to our build server and restarted these three services:

[image]

In our case, it was just a problem with a single pipeline, as the other pipeline we use was running ok.  I don't know why one pipeline worked and the other didn't since they both use the same agent, but restarting the services resolved it.

Comment: In my case I was running the cmd line version of the agent for interactive support. After installing visualstudio build tools I had to restart that. Essentially the same answer and I realized that thanks to this answer.

Comment: This was it for me. I had just installed Visual Studio to fix the issue but DevOps didn't pick up that change until I restarted Azure DevOps services on the build server.

Answer (score 1):

Same here.
We have the same issue and MS is tracking it.
https://twitter.com/AzureDevOps/status/1207288336206815232

Comment: We noticed that the issue happens when we use the DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task

Comment: The issue seems to appear only with 2nd stage builds: https://dev.azure.com/rmetzger/Flink/_build/results?buildId=3732&view=logs&j=f0e00a00-1020-5968-9a5d-4286b06762e6 (but they also contain a `DownloadPipelineArtifact` task.

Comment: I just realized that there's a 2.163 release for the agents already. Just updating them fixes the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I created a new agent.
This new agent didn't receive existing `User-defined capabilities` that were on older agents.

After comparing agent capabilities, I added the missing user-defined capabilitiesies and it started to compile.

Answer (score 0):

In your pipeline definition YML file you have to specify 'windows-2016' before specifying agentpool, see below:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'IaC Build'
  variables:
  - name: var
    value: val
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
          vmImage: 'windows-2016'
    steps:
    - task: ...
# Deploy Dev 
- stage: DeployDevInfra
  displayName: 'Deploy: DEV'
  dependsOn: build
  variables:
  - group: your-var-group
  - name: var
    value: val
  jobs:
  - template: another-pipeline.yml
    parameters:
      agentpool: 'here-come-name-of-your-agent-pool'
      environment: 'your-dev-environment'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to delete and recreate the Release Pipeline and it started working. None of the other answers worked/applied for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - downloaded a self-hosting agent and ran it. I downloaded it after opening my custom AgentPool, so I expected that the agent will be found there. The issue was, the agent was still created in the Default pool (me being a newbie in this). End result was I was trying to use the wrong Agent pool, that would cause the same issue.